# how to upload file in laravel with taking the desired name

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing an error while uploading a file it is saying that the Undefined variable: `filenametostore`.

This is my controller :

```
if(!$validator->fails()){
    $cate = Product::where('name','=',$request->product_name)->first();
    if($cate){
        $arr = array('status'=>'false-1','message'=>'Product name already exist');
    }else{
        $cat = new Product();
        $cat->name = $request->product_name;
        $cat->category_id = $request->product_category;
        $cat->brand_id = $request->product_brand;
        $cat->quantity = $request->product_quantity;
        $cat->buy_per_piece = $request->product_buying_per_piece;
        $cat->sell_per_piece = $request->product_selling_per_piece;
        if($request->hasFile('thumbnail')){
            $filenameExt = $request->file('thumbnail')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('thumbnail')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filenametostore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            $request->file('thumbnail')->move(public_path('images'), $filenametostore);
        }
        $cat->image = $filenametostore;
        $cat->save();

        $arr = array('status'=>'true','message'=>'Successfully Inserted');
    }
}else{
    $arr = array('status'=>'false','message'=>$validator->errors()->all());
}
```

please help me to rectify the error

Comment: You will get error about undefined variable always when your condition if($request->hasFile('thumbnail')) is false. Could you please check do you really have file with name thumbnail in your request (form input with this name for example)

Comment: no i have `dd($request->hasFile('thumbnail'))` it was saying true just what if `$cat->image = $filenametostore` then fileis not uploading saying the `filenametostore` is not defined

Comment: Move `$cat->image = $filenametostore;` to inside of `if($request->hasFile('thumbnail'))` condition.

Comment: @iamab.in tried that too then file does not gets uploaded rather than that everything gets uploaded

Comment: put a `dd($filenametostore)` as the last line of the `if($request->hasFile('thumbnail'))` condition and let us know the result

Comment: @iamab.in tried that too and its showing the filename like `dummy.jpg` i am not able to get what the actual problem is

Comment: What errors show now?

Comment: @iamab.in There is no error but the file is not getting uploaded form is getting submitted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221501/discussion-between-iamab-in-and-babai).

Comment: @iamab.in Okay lets do it